# DatePicker in Yii2 GridView not filtering date

Tags: php, gridview, datepicker, yii2

I'm using Yii2 default GridView and I embedded kartik datepicker (`use kartik\widgets\DatePicker`) into one of the filtering inputs like this:

```
'attribute' => 'register_date',
'format' =>  ['date', 'dd.MM.Y'],
'headerOptions' => ['width'=>'120', 'style'=>'text-align:center'],
'filter' => DatePicker::widget([
    'name' => 'register_date',
    'language' => 'ru',
    'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_INPUT,
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'autoclose'=>false,
        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    ]
])
```

Now if I select date from DatePicker, the page just reloads and NO FILTERING HAPPENS. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't apply filtering by default. Try to submit the form based onInput event

Comment: Show server side related code.

Comment: can you put your search model code?